# Where can I find a copy of Shunichi Muraso's 'Mystery of Easter Island'?

Tags: mystery-of-easter-island

I am the curator of an exhibition on Easter Island in popular culture (http://www.moaiculture.com) and I am trying to track down a few missing items. If you can assist we will acknowledge you in the exhibition. Can anyone advise as to where I may view online or buy a copy of Shunichi Muraso's 'Mystery of Easter Island'?

[image]

Comment: A good place to start would be by looking up the author here- https://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=11988